# SQL statement returns no results if table in NOT IN segment is empty

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Running into a problem where I get no results at all if there isn't a tool currently checked out (checkinout table is currently empty).  Once I have a single record entered into checkinout table, I start getting the list of tools that aren't currently checked out.  It isn't Earth shattering if I have to put in a false checkout history, but I would prefer not having to do that.  Any ideas on how I can fix this?  Thanks.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tools.id, 
       tools.ToolNumber, 
       tools.Description
  FROM tools, 
       checkinout
 WHERE tools.id NOT IN(SELECT checkinout.idTool 
                         FROM checkinout 
                        WHERE checkinout.CheckInDT IS NULL)
       AND tools.Retired=0 
ORDER BY 
       tools.ToolNumber;
```

Comment: http://blog.9minutesnooze.com/sql-not-in-subquery-null. Maybe a `JOIN` would help here, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do this with a `LEFT JOIN`, where the column on the RIGHT is null

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg) is a helpful image showing SQL Joins

```
SELECT DISTINCT tools.id,
       tools.ToolNumber,
       tools.Description
FROM tools
LEFT JOIN checkinout 
    ON tools.id = checkinout.idTool AND checkinout.CheckInDT IS NULL
WHERE checkinout.idTool IS NULL
AND tools.retired = 0
ORDER BY tools.ToolNumber
```

Comment: Gah! I miss some of the simplest things some times.  That did it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use 2 tables? You never join on `checkinout`.

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT tools.id, 
       tools.ToolNumber, 
       tools.Description
  FROM tools        
 WHERE tools.id NOT IN (
                        SELECT checkinout.idTool 
                          FROM checkinout 
                         WHERE checkinout.CheckInDT IS NULL
                       )
       AND tools.Retired=0
ORDER BY 
       tools.ToolNumber;
```

Comment: Although, this is correct observation, it does not adress the main issue

Comment: Yeah i upvoted Tom's answer as it is the better one.

Answer (score 0):

Because nobody mentioned `EXISTS` yet (you can probably get rid of the DISTINCT this way):

```
SELECT tools.id, 
       tools.ToolNumber, 
       tools.Description
  FROM tools
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * 
                      FROM checkinout 
                     WHERE checkinout.CheckInDT IS NULL
                       AND checkinout.idTool = tools.id )
   AND tools.Retired=0 
ORDER BY 
       tools.ToolNumber;
```